# x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc to develop Windows for a VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, gcc

Is there a way to pass the handle of a file opened in a VB.NET application to a DLL created on a Linux system using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc. The dll should be able to write to the open file.

Some pseduo code snippet Below:

On VB side:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("testFile.dll",
   SetLastError:=False)>
    Public Shared Function PassFile(ByVal fNo As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Dim buffer(4096) As Byte 
        Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream("tmppath.txt", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            Me.Text = outFile.Write(buffer, 0, 2048)
            PassFile(outFile.Handle)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

On C side:

```
int __cdecl PassFile(int fnum)
{
     char buffer[] = "This is a test of '_write' function";
     if (write(fnum, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != sizeof(buffer)){
          return 0;
     }else{
         return -1
     }
}
```

Compiling with the following commands to create the dll
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -o add.o add.c
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared -o add.dll add.o -nostdlib -s -mwindows -Wl,--subsystem,windows

Comment: NO you cannot pass a file handle from vb.net to c, they are totally different, you will have to close the file in vb and reopen it by name in the c code

Comment: If the dll is compiled using the Microsoft C++ compiler, then would it be possible?

Comment: The file handle you get from VB is the windows file handle. `write` expects a file number. You can read or write it in C using win32 call `ReadFile` and `WriteFIle`, why not just pass the file name tho?